# Can d-i (Ubuntu installer) configure bond, vlan and second network interface during the installation?

Tags: networking, system-installation

I'm just wondering whether the current d-i can configure the bond, vlan, software raid and other network interfaces during the installation, other than by tweaking and hacking the preseed file?

I believe these functions are quite common, but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: Software RAID, yes, I think can be done: https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/installation-guide/amd64/apbs04.html#preseed-partman-raid. I don't think a secondary network interface can be set up during installation. [No options for vlan](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2013/10/msg02095.html), either. What is a bond?

Comment: Hey muru, thanks for your answer, what I mean about bond should be network bonding, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @muru I suggest adding an answer to this question. I believe it would be much helpful. I think this is the latest documentation on the topic https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/apb.html

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found out to configure VLAN, Network Bonding and second NIC is by tweaking last_command, which is not very straightforward.

I'm sad to see such common requests are not even implemented in d-i today.

Comment: Thank you for reporting back - could you add some explanation/detail on **how** you accomplished your goals (at least *somewhat*). Handling of `d-i` is not a thing many people are knowledgeable about, so your answer could be valuable.

Comment: Hey gunbert, I don't have debian environment at hand atm, but if you look at some d-i installation manifest (something like kickstart to redhat), you might find there is last_command keyword.  Or if you can look at the curtin in /etc/maas (Mental As A Service), you will find last_command

Comment: Automated installations are ways to get a system ready without being delayed for luxury tasks. Configuring a second NIC got less priority for this reason imo